# How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in NodeJS and then find the index of that substring in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am able to determine the first part of the question which is to return true if a string contains text from an array of substrings in NodeJS using this:

```
var allowedRoles = [
    "Area Director",
    "Managing Director",
    "Group Director"];

var currentRole = "USA Managing Director";
var lifeSaver = allowedRoles.some((substring) =>
    currentRole.includes(substring)
);
console.log(lifeSaver);
```

Here my result is true.
But, I want to know that where in the allowedRole array my result returned true. (Expected answer: 1);

Comment: You can replace `.some()` with `.findIndex()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.some` you can use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The **findIndex()** method returns the index of the first element in the
>   array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it
>   returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.

```
var lifeSaver = allowedRoles.findIndex((substring) =>    
    currentRole.includes(substring)
);
```